# How to compile for multiple versions of windows where Kernel32 entry point may not exist for some functions

Tags: c++, windows, kernel32

The title may not be the most descriptive at first:

I have a program that utilizes a call to ["Wow64EnableWow64FsRedirection" function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-wow64enablewow64fsredirection) which is required when the software runs on a Windows 7 and Windows 10 64-bit platform.

However, the same application must also be able to run on a 32-bit Windows XP platform. The problem is, kernel32.dll for the Windows XP platform doesn't have the entry point for the Wow64 Redirect function and my application fails to execute at all.

Within the application, I have a check for the OS version and I handle the method calls separately based on the version; in other words, if the application is running on the 32-bit system I never attempt to call the WoW64 Redirect function.

I am unable to compile a platform-specific version for the 32-bit and 64-bit OSes.

Is there anything I can do to support the application on both platforms?

Comment: Amend the example from the MS-Docs _"...If the function might not exist in the DLL module—for example, if the function is available only on Windows Vista but the application might be running on Windows XP..."_ : - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getprocaddress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `hModule = LoadLibrary("kernel32.dll")` and `func = GetProcAddress(hModule, "Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection")` if header file is not available for specific platforms.